# How to split Rspec tests to run on several hosts

Tags: selenium, rspec, capybara

I use rspec, Capybara, Selenium, WebMock, Sinatra proxy, and curb to run our GUI tests (700+ so far in different spec files).
Our configuration in general: we have a local server that serves the files for the web application, Selenium and Capybara handle the browser interaction, Sinatra proxy with WebMock in order to stub the requests.

I'm looking for a way to cut this run time into less than a minute,
a single run of rspec will take 45 minutes+. the average run for each spec is less then a minute, although some specs can take up to 3 minutes.

I've tried browserstack and saucelab and parallel tests(https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests), all fails in a non consistent random way, while running the tests on my Ubuntu the tests are consistent as expected.

I'm looking for a way to split the work load to a list of hosts (whom will be pre-configured most likely).

Before I move into writing some script to do it I was wondering if there is anything out there that can do this work for me? 
any ideas or solutions are more than welcome.

Comment: you can use tagging for parallelisation.  For a single machine you can use 8 tag that you can fire them separately for parallel processing and check the result regularly if finished.

Comment: parallel_tests has support for just running a specific portion of the tests  - https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests/wiki/Distributed-Parallel-Tests-and-Travis-Support - without doing any other database setup, etc. However if all of your attempts at running are ending in random failures it may be better to figure out why since you'll probably have similar issues if scripting it all yourself.  What type of errors were you getting?